# Redux-saga with redux-toolkit returning empty object and consoling the response shows promise{<pending>}

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Hey guys I am a beginner and trying to learn `redux-saga` with `redux-toolkit`. I am getting an empty user object and when I consoled the axios response, it is showing all the data, but not in handler.

this is the code.

UserInfoSlice

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const userInfoSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        user: {},
    },

    reducers: {
        getUser() {},

        setUser(state, action) {
            const userInfo = action.payload;
            console.log(userInfo)
            return {...state, ...userInfo};
        }
    },
})


export const {getUser, setUser} = userInfoSlice.actions;

export const selectUserInfo = state => state.user.user;

export default userInfoSlice.reducer;
```

store

```
import {configureStore, combineReducers, getDefaultMiddleware} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import {watcherSaga} from '../saga/RootSaga';

import userinfoReducer from '../features/UserInfoSlice';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const reducers = combineReducers({
    user: userinfoReducer,
});
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: reducers,
    middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware({thunk: false}), sagaMiddleware]
});

sagaMiddleware.run(watcherSaga);

export default store;
```

rootsaga

```
import { takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";
import {handlegetUserInfo} from './handlers/UserInfo';
import {getUser} from '../features/UserInfoSlice';






export function* watcherSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(getUser.type, handlegetUserInfo)
}
```

userInfoHandler

```
import { call, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { requestGetUserInfo } from '../requests/UserInforequest';
import { setUser } from "../../features/UserInfoSlice";


export function* handlegetUserInfo() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(requestGetUserInfo);
        console.log(response)
        const { data } = response;
        console.log(data);
        yield put(setUser({ ...data }))    
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

userinforequest

```
import axiosInstance from '../../../axios';


export function* requestGetUserInfo() {
    return axiosInstance.get('api/user/')
}
```

please let me know what I have done wrong here and how to resolve this.?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Generator vs. Async

You are defining `requestGetUserInfo` as a generator function with `function*`.  This means that you need to `yield` the result.

```
export function* requestGetUserInfo() {
  return yield axios.get('api/user/');
}
```

Alternatively, you can define it as an `async` function and `await` the result.

```
export async function requestGetUserInfo() {
  return await axios.get('api/user/');
}
```

#### Slice Shape

Depending on the shape of your API response, there **might** be an issue in your `setUser` case reducer.

The `initialState` of your `userInfoSlice` declares that this is an object with a property `user`.  Your `setUser` reducer sets the properties from the `action.payload` `userInfo` as top-level properties of the `state`.  This would only be ok your API returns an object with a property `user`.  More likely, it returns the user object and you'd want to set this `userInfo` to the `user` property of your state.

```
setUser(state, action) {
  const userInfo = action.payload;
  console.log("payload", userInfo);
  return { ...state, user: userInfo };
}
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-saga-fetch-user-f5epw)